# python MySQL 5.7 and CTE

Tags: python, mysql

I'm migrating some databases from our bigquery servers and can't find a way or roundabout CTE. I have a few tables which contains timezone manipulations or simple calculations, but no way or answer I've tried works. My SQL knowledge is limited and without WITH clauses I'm at a loss. Retrieving it in a dataframe is what I aim

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='guest', password='pwd',
                              host='ip',
                              database='db'
                              )

query = ("CREATE VIEW a AS SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(FECHA_HORA_REAL, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%') AS date FROM  pm_tv; LEFT JOIN (SELECT  * from kpi ) b ON b.FECHA_HORA_MINUTO = a.date")
query2 = ("SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(FECHA_HORA_REAL, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%') AS date FROM pm_tv b LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from kpi) a ON a.FECHA_HORA_MINUTO = b.date")
```

Which I execute with:

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, multi = True)
for _ in cursor:
    print(_)
```

or

```
df = pd.read_sql(query,cnx)
df.head()
```

The first query returns duplicated table a already exist, the second returns unkwown column name a.date.

Between the two ways of executing, the first forced me to used multi= True but theres seems to be no choice like that in pandas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you can't use Values from the select at that position, they could be used in a HAVING clause.
So use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW a1 AS
    SELECT 
        STR_TO_DATE(FECHA_HORA_REAL, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%') AS date
    FROM
        pm_tv
            LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            kpi) b ON b.FECHA_HORA_MINUTO = STR_TO_DATE(pm_tv.FECHA_HORA_REAL, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%');


SELECT 
    *, STR_TO_DATE(FECHA_HORA_REAL, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%') AS date
FROM
    pm_tv b
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        kpi) a ON a.FECHA_HORA_MINUTO = STR_TO_DATE(b.FECHA_HORA_REAL, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%')
```

Bythe way MySQL 6,7 has no CTE, it was only imolemented in MySQL 8

Comment: Thanks! It still returns "table a already exist" error with pandas, and null table with mysql cursor. I'll check the HAVING tutorial, never used it

Comment: you have teh same name for the view as for the alias for the second tabke, that is of course not possible you need to rename the view i called it now a1